# import error for awsglue.context import GlueContext

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I recently installed python 3.7 and trying to play around with pyspark, I need to create

```
    glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
    sparkSession = glueContext.spark_session
```

for which when I import library its just failing to find dynamicframe

When I try to import from `awsglue.context import GlueContext` I get following error

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dynamicframe'
```

even this one is failing

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dynamicframe'
```

Pyspark module seems to have no problem importing `from pyspark.context import SparkContext`

There is no proper documentation on how to setup libraries needed.

Folder structure under  `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue`

```
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── context.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── data_sink.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── data_source.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── functions.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── gluetypes.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── job.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── utils.cpython-37.pyc
├── context.py
├── data_sink.py
├── data_source.py
├── devutils.py
├── dynamicframe.py
├── functions.py
├── gluetypes.py
├── job.py
├── transforms
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── apply_mapping.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── collection_transforms.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── dynamicframe_filter.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── dynamicframe_map.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── errors_as_dynamicframe.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── field_transforms.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── relationalize.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── resolve_choice.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── transform.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── unbox.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── unnest_frame.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── apply_mapping.py
│   ├── collection_transforms.py
│   ├── drop_nulls.py
│   ├── dynamicframe_filter.py
│   ├── dynamicframe_map.py
│   ├── errors_as_dynamicframe.py
│   ├── field_transforms.py
│   ├── relationalize.py
│   ├── resolve_choice.py
│   ├── transform.py
│   ├── unbox.py
│   └── unnest_frame.py
└── utils.py
```

Comment: Can you share your folder structure

Comment: @GrandPhuba How can I get that ? New to python

Comment: Share the files and folders of your project. Screenshot or text is fine

Comment: @GrandPhuba updated in question

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same while trying to setup Glue Pyspark on my local machine.